# Как реализовать выгрузку элементов инфоблока из Битрикс в 1С?

Tags: битрикс

Доброе время суток!

Натолкните на мысль или подскажите, как реализовать выгрузку элементов инфоблока из Битрикс в 1С...
Нужно реализовать обмен возвратами, предыдущий программист реализовал форму возврата через инфоблоки...
Теперь нужно выгружать данные этих инфоблоков в 1С...

Comment: Если платформа 1С поддерживает REST API. То на стороне сайта можно написать обработку, которая будет вносить изменения в документы 1С.

Comment: к сожалению, коллеги на стороне 1С готовы работать только через SOAP

Comment: Можно и через SOAP попробовать сделать. Создать файл который будет выбирать в битриксе данные, а в 1С сделать обработку, которая будет их забирать. Формат вобщем-то абсолютно неважен, можете даже через xml обмениваться.